# Table per Hierarchy and Table per Concrete type in Enttiy Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the following POCO model classes:

```
//Not mapped to table, has all fields apart from foreign key
public abstract class FirstBaseModel {}

//Mapped to a table, has foreign key (eg. customerId)
public class Derived1Model : FirstBaseModel {}

//Mapped to a different table, has foreign key (eg. companyId)
public class Derived2Model : FirstBaseModel {}

//Mapped to the same table as Derived2Model
public class Derived3Model : Derived2Model {}
```

In the above scenario would I be mixing Table-per-Type and Table-per-Hierarchy inheritance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TPH is the default in a standard scenario.
If you need TPT you just need to specify the table name.

In your case (I added also some properties)

```
//Not mapped to table, has all fields apart from foreign key
public abstract class FirstBaseModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

//Mapped to a table, has foreign key (eg. customerId)
[Table("MyTable")]
public class Derived1Model : FirstBaseModel
{
    public string D1 { get; set; }
}

//Mapped to a different table, has foreign key (eg. companyId)
[Table("MyDifferentTable")]
public class Derived2Model : FirstBaseModel
{
    public string D2 { get; set; }
}

//Mapped to the same table as Derived2Model
[Table("MyDifferentTable")]
public class Derived3Model : Derived2Model
{
    public string D3 { get; set; }
}
```

This are the queries that EF runs on database

```
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE TABLE [MyTable] (
 [Id] int not null identity(1,1)
, [D1] text null
);
ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable_b9ce81de] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE TABLE [MyDifferentTable] (
 [Id] int not null identity(1,1)
, [D2] text null
, [D3] text null
, [Discriminator] varchar(128) not null
);
ALTER TABLE [MyDifferentTable] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_MyDifferentTable_b9ce81de] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
```